# How can I assert that assertion A or assertion B passes with Junit 4?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Junit 4 w/ Selenium WebDriver for some automated testing.  I have a test that records some values on a page, clicks a button on the page to load the next page and then compares the recorded value to make sure they changed.

The problem is it's a *PAIR* of values and only one of them has to change, not both.

For testing it I've currently implemented the following code:

```
boolean orderNumberChanged = true;
try
{
  assertThat(orderNumber,
             is(not(getValueForElement(By.name("updateForm:j_id35")))));

}
catch (AssertionError ae) { orderNumberChanged = false; }
try
{
  assertThat(orderDate,
             is(not(getValueForElement(By.name("updateForm:j_id37")))));

}
catch (AssertionError ae)
{
  if ( !orderNumberChanged )
  { fail("OrderNumber and OrderDate didn't change."); }
}
```

While it should work perfectly fine it just *looks* ugly to me and it seams like there should be some way to assert something like this.

For the record `getValueForElement()` is a method I wrote to wrap
`driver.findElement(locator).getAttribute("value");`

Comment: Why not simply `assertTrue(orderNumber != ... || orderDate != ...);`?  (Or whatever the logic is.)

Comment: At one point I was doing something like the `assertTrue()` you suggest.  I was just hoping some enterprising individual had created `assertOr(assert, assert)` or `assertOr(object, matcher, object, matcher)` (or something similar) basically I don't like non-descriptive "AssertionError" granted `assertTrue("didn't change", /* logic here */);` would work, I just prefer matcher errors that include the actual details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer/comment suggesting `assertTrue(orderNumber.equals(...) || orderDate.equals(...));` is indeed the simplest and most direct solution.  However, I also wanted better error messages than just **AssertionError**

In order to do that was not trivial.  I'm working with Selenium WebDriver so the actual data being checked belongs to a `WebDriver` object.

I found my answer thanks to this: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/ blog post.

It turns out that Hamcrest has a `CombinableMatcher` class and a `CombinableEitherMatcher`

I ended up copying `CombinableEitherMatcher`'s logic to create my own class `Neither`

```
public class Neither<X> 
{
  /**
   * Creates a matcher that matches when neither of the specified matchers 
   * match the examined object.
   * <p/>
   * For example:
   * <pre>
   * assertThat("fan", neither(containsString("a")).nor(containsString("b")))
   * </pre>
   */
  public static <LHS> Neither<LHS> neither(Matcher<LHS> matcher)
  { return new Neither<LHS>(matcher); }

  private final Matcher<X> first;

  public Neither(Matcher<X> matcher) { this.first = not(matcher); }

  public CombinableMatcher<X> nor(Matcher<X> other)
  { return new CombinableMatcher<X>(first).or(not(other)); }

  /**
   *  Helper class to do the heavy lifting and provide a usable error
   *  from: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/
   */
  private class WebElementCombinableMatcher extends BaseMatcher<WebElement>
  {
     private final List<Matcher<WebElement>> matchers = new ArrayList<Matcher<WebElement>>();
     private final List<Matcher<WebElement>> failed = new ArrayList<Matcher<WebElement>>();

     private WebElementCombinableMatcher(final Matcher matcher)
     { matchers.add(matcher); }

     public WebElementCombinableMatcher and(final Matcher matcher) 
     {
        matchers.add(matcher);
        return this;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean matches(final Object item)
     {
        for (final Matcher<WebElement> matcher : matchers)
        {
           if (!matcher.matches(item))
           {
              failed.add(matcher);
              return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
     }

     @Override
     public void describeTo(final Description description)
     { description.appendList("(", " " + "and" + " ", ")", matchers); }

     @Override
     public void describeMismatch(final Object item, final Description description)
     {
        for (final Matcher<WebElement> matcher : failed)
        {
           description.appendDescriptionOf(matcher).appendText(" but ");
           matcher.describeMismatch(item, description);
        }
     }    

  }

}
```

which lets me call 
`assertThat(driver, niether(matcher(x)).nor(matcher(y));`

Since I'm trying to compare specific WebElements obtainable from driver I had to create matchers that I could use inside of *niether/nor*

For Example:

```
public class WebElementValueMatcher extends FeatureMatcher<WebDriver, String>
{
   public static Matcher<WebDriver> elementHasValue(final By locator,
                                                    String elementValue)
   { return new WebElementValueMatcher(equalTo(elementValue), locator); }

   public static Matcher<WebDriver> elementHasValue(final By locator,
                                                    Matcher<String> matcher)
   { return new WebElementValueMatcher(matcher, locator); }

   By locator;

   public WebElementValueMatcher(Matcher<String> subMatcher, By locator)
   {
      super(subMatcher, locator.toString(), locator.toString());
      this.locator = locator;
   }

   public WebElementValueMatcher(Matcher<String> subMatcher,
                                 String featureDescription, String featureName)
   { super(subMatcher, featureDescription, featureName); }

   @Override
   protected String featureValueOf(WebDriver actual)
   { return actual.findElement(locator).getAttribute("value"); }

}
```

I have another very similar one that calls `actual.findElement(locator).getText();` in *featureValueOf*

However now I can simply call

```
assertThat(driver, 
           niether(elementHasValue(By.id("foo"),"foo"))
              .nor(elementHasValue(By.id("bar"),"bar")));`
```

and get clean syntax in my tests and a usable error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a hamcrest style without severe contortions that make it much less readable than falling back to `assertTrue`.

Just do

```
assertTrue(orderNumber.equals(...) || orderDate.equals(...));
```

The new `assertThat` requires matching against a single object, so you'd have to put them into an array or something in order to get it through.

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer is complete but I think it is outdated and you need to code a lot. for anyone that is looking for a more simpler solution, you can achieve the same functionality as below:

1)

```
assertThat(actual).isIn(expected1, expected2);
```

2. 

```
assertThat(actual, anyOf(is(expected1), is(expected2)));
```

3. 

```
assertThat(actual, isOneOf(expected1, expected2));
```

4. 

```
String expectedTitles[] = {"expected1","expected2"};
List<String> expectedTitlesList = Arrays.asList(expectedTitles);

assertTrue(expectedTitlesList.contains((actual)));
```